# How to download today's date file from server hosted on WebDAV protocol using HTTP connection in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There are list of files placed on server which is based on WebDAV protocol. I want to copy today's date file into Azure blob storage using copy activity.
For example if today's date is 01-Mar-2024 i.e. 20240301, below highlighted file should get copied.

[image]

So for achieving this I created HTTP connection and in relative url path I gave filename path with wildcard characters as
@concat('src/order/orderExport-Invoice-',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyddMM'),'*.xml')'

[image]

But HTTP connection unable to recognize wildcard characters and unable to convert into actual filename, getting below error:

[image]

Is there any way through which we can dynamically copy the file for today's date from server(WebDAV) ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this process but is there a way that you can get the newest file always? Like using Last Modified date instead of getting by the name of the file? Just thinking out loud here

Comment: Not sure about it, previously we used to provide filename manually in HTTP relative url connection and download the file. But as we need to automate process we need to pass filename dynamically during run time. Any help on this, appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: @user2783444, Is there a way that you can get list of all the file names from HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach below to download today's date file:

Run the following code in Azure Databricks to get a list of files in the URL:

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read_url(url):
    url = url.replace(" ", "%20")
    req = Request(url)
    a = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
    x = (soup.find_all('a'))
    url_list = []
    for i in x:
        file_name = i.extract().get_text()
        url_new = url + file_name
        url_new = url_new.replace(" ", "%20")
        if file_name[-1] == '/' and file_name[0] != '.':
            url_list.extend(read_url(url_new))
        else:
            url_list.append(url_new)
    return url_list

urls = read_url("<url>")
dbutils.notebook.exit(urls)
```

Create a pipeline in ADF with a Databricks Notebook activity with the following [Databricks linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#create-an-azure-databricks-linked-service) configuration:

[image: Databricks linked service configuration]

Select the notebook and run it. Then you will get the files in the URL as output of the Databricks Notebook activity. Add a filter activity to the Notebook activity with an expression for `@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput` item and `@contains(item().name,concat('orderExport-Invoice-',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')) )` expression for the condition. Then you will get the filtered items for the sample as shown below:

[image: Filtered items]

Add a ForEach activity to the Filter activity with `@activity('Filter1').output.Value` items. Create an HTTP linked service using the pipeline parameter **baseurl** for the base URL `@{linkedService().baseurl}`, create a parameter **url** at the dataset level, and add it as a value to **baseurl** as `@dataset().url`. Add `@item()` as a value to the **url** parameter. Don't mention a relative URL for the dataset; the filter activity will provide the complete URL. Add the required sink to the Copy activity. Those files will download successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much for above detailed explanation. I just wanted to know where I can provide my actual URL link with username and password like in HTTP connection we provide base and relative URL with username and password. In the above example, how our URL is going to authenticate without username and password ? Does that need to be provided in notebook code ?

Comment: Provide username and password in linked service itself, if those details vary from URL to URL use parameters.